# Find count of sub_string in string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Why is this giving output as 1 and not 2:

```
string = "ABCDCDC"
print(string.count("CDC"))
```

Also, since this is not working, how can I get 2 in this case?

Comment: Because `count` method doesn't take overlapping substrings into account.

Comment: @Kasramvd okay, but then how do I count overlapping substrings?

Comment: Don't use `string` as a variable name

Comment: @user3483203 what's so bad about using `string` as a variable name? I'd be more worried about using `str` as a variable name, since that is a built-in function.

Comment: @Joel `string` is a module https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an algorithmic solution

```
string = "ABCDCDC"
sub_string = "CDC"

count = 0
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i:len(sub_string)+i] == sub_string:
        count += 1 
print count
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to count overlapping substrings:

```
import re
string = "ABCDCDC"
print(len(re.findall('(?=CDC)', string))) # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print([m.start() for m in re.finditer('(?=CDC)', 'ABCDCDC')])
```

This should find all potentially overlapping occurences

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple way:

```
def overlapping_count(string, seek):
    seek_len = len(seek)
    return sum(c == seek[0] and string[i:i + seek_len] == seek
                  for i, c in enumerate(string))
string = "ABCDCDC"
print(overlapping_count(string, "CDC"))
```